# HowTo use ByteBuddy to measure time taken by annotaion marked methods intrumented via agent

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm using ByteBuddy to make some perfomance measuremnts of certian methods. Therefore, I'm annotating the interessting ones. As the method signature is not stable, I choose the generic way for my interceptor:

```
public class ChronometryInterception {

  @RuntimeType
  public Object intercept(@Origin MethodHandle methodHandle, @AllArguments Object[] allArguments, @Origin Method method) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("in interceptor");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        return methodHandle.invoke(allArguments);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("ex in interceptor " + e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println("took " + elapsedTime;

    }
  }
}
```

and I bind it in my premain() like this

```
ChronometryInterception chronometryInterception = new ChronometryInterception();

new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
    .type(declaresMethod(isAnnotatedWith(Timed.class)))
      .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> builder
        .method(isAnnotatedWith(Timed.class))
                 .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(chronometryInterception))
      ).installOn(instrumentation);
```

In the listener stream, I can see the annotated classes have been transformed and they try to do something, but in end up with a NPE. Using the debugger, I'm not getting anywhere in the ChronometryInterception. Any way out? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give the stack trace of the exception? Also, try defining the interception method as `static` rather then delegating to an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a working solution. At the end, the method signature of my interceptor was not ok. This one is working, even with an instance of the ChronometryInterception:

```
public class ChronometryInterception {

  @RuntimeType
  public Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> zuper) throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        return zuper.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
      long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
      System.out.println("took " + elapsedTime);
    }
  }

}
```